# Importing csv into mysql wont work properly

Tags: mysql, csv, replication

I have this database table:

[image: this]

and I am trying to import a csv, which has the following structure:

```
first_name,last_name,street,number,locality,country,postal_code,birthdate,birth_place,created_at,last_updated,owner_id,nationality,user_id
Ronald,Hofmann,Wilhelmstrasse,387,Berlin,Germany,12043,2005-06-15,Koeln,20190710171824,20190710171824,15,Deutsch,14
Horst-Dieter,Wulff,Markgrafendamm,448,Berlin,Germany,12157,1978-05-20,Muenchen,20190710171824,20190710171824,16,Deutsch,15
Jaqueline,Meister,Markgrafendamm,296,Berlin,Germany,10115,1954-07-06,Hamburg,20190710171824,20190710171824,17,Deutsch,16
```

using the following MySQL code:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\csv\\licence_owner.csv' 
INTO TABLE licence_owner
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Despite that when I run the code I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: 'Koeln' for column 'birthdate' at row 1
```

I have the feeling that maybe the `-` inside the date provoce this error, as they could work like a comma and perhaps when they are encountered the next column is being parsed? I dont fully understand why this error occurs. Does anyone know how I could go about it? I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is missing the middle name.  Use a column list to load the data:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\csv\\licence_owner.csv' 
    INTO TABLE licence_owner
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    ENCLOSED BY ''
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS
    (first_name, last_name, street, number, locality, country, postal_code,
     birthdate, birth_place, created_at, last_updated, owner_id, 
     nationality, user_id
    )
```